# Oracle SQL create rollup totals

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the following test data and I could use some help generating the following output

```
    YEAR 2021 
       Week 30
         1  Smith,Jane HRS 11  MIN 45  SEC 08
         2   Doe,John HRS 07  MIN 01  SEC 11

     Week Total HRS 18  MIN 46  SEC 19

     Week 31
         1   Smith,Jane HRS 13 MIN 36 SEC 01
         2   Doe,John HRS 03 MIN 27 SEC 00

    Week Total  HRS 17 MIN 03 SEC 01

    Year Total   HRS 35 MIN 49 SEC 20
```

I want to extract every unique YYYY from the emp_attendance table then create totals for YYYY (year total).

Within each YYYY (sample only has 2 week numbers 30,31 but there can be up to 52 per year) I want to create week number totals.

Within each week number I want totals for each employee_id.

I've used the following query to get hours, min, sec but I'm unsure how to roll up the data to produce the several totals I want in my sample output above. I prefer an ALL sql solution.

```
    select  
     e.employee_id       
     e.first_name,
     e.last_name,
     trunc(sum(a.end_date - a.start_date) * 24) hours,
   
    trunc(mod(sum(a.end_date - a.start_date) * 24 * 60,60)) minutes,

    round(mod(sum(a.end_date - a.start_date) * 24 * 60 * 60,60)) seconds

   from  employees e,
    emp_attendance a

    where a.employee_id = e.employee_id 
    group by e.employee_id, e.first_name, e.last_name

   order by e.employee_id, e.first_name,
       e.last_name;

    Emp Fname Lname  hrs  min sec
    1      Jane     Smith    25   21   9
    2      John     Doe      10   28  11
```

My test case.

```
    ALTER SESSION SET NLS_DATE_FORMAT = 'MMDDYYYY HH24:MI:SS';

    Create table employees(
     employee_id NUMBER(6), 
     first_name VARCHAR2(20),
     last_name VARCHAR2(20) 
   );

    Insert into employees (employee_id, 
     first_name,
      last_name) values
       (1, 'Jane', 'Smith');

    Insert into employees (employee_id, 
    first_name,last_name)
    values(2, 'John', 'Doe');

    CREATE TABLE  emp_attendance(    
    
    seq_num integer  GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY (START WITH 1) NOT NULL,
   employee_id NUMBER(6),
   start_date DATE,
   end_date DATE,
   week_number NUMBER(2),
   create_date DATE DEFAULT SYSDATE
   );


    INSERT INTO emp_attendance (employee_id, start_date, end_date,  week_number)VALUES (1, to_date('20210714 18:35:40','YYYYMMDD HH24:MI:SS'), to_date('20210715 02:34:56','YYYYMMDD HH24:MI:SS'),30);


    INSERT INTO emp_attendance (employee_id, start_date, end_date,  week_number)        VALUES (1, to_date('20210715 19:37:10','YYYYMMDD HH24:MI:SS'), to_date('20210715 23:23:02','YYYYMMDD HH24:MI:SS'),30);


    INSERT INTO emp_attendance (employee_id, c start_date, end_date,  week_number)VALUES (1, to_date('20210722 09:17:11','YYYYMMDD HH24:MI:SS'), to_date('20210722 22:53:12','YYYYMMDD HH24:MI:SS'),31);

    INSERT INTO emp_attendance (employee_id, start_date, end_date,  week_number)
     VALUES (2, to_date('20210716 18:24:11','YYYYMMDD HH24:MI:SS'), to_date('20210717 01:25:22','YYYYMMDD HH24:MI:SS'),30);

    INSERT INTO emp_attendance (employee_id, start_date, end_date,  week_number)
    VALUES (2, to_date('20210722 09:17:11','YYYYMMDD HH24:MI:SS'),      to_date('20210722 12:44:11','YYYYMMDD HH24:MI:SS'),31);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `GROUPING SETS` clause is useful for creating multiple aggregations, and the [`GROUPING_ID`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/GROUPING_ID.html#GUID-E20A5B8E-73B6-42FD-8AFB-DD3CD6D6DC61) function is useful for identifying which aggregation each row is a part of.

For example:

```
select
    to_char(a.start_date, 'YYYY') the_year,
    week_number,
    e.employee_id,
    e.first_name,
    e.last_name,
    trunc(sum(a.end_date - a.start_date) * 24) hours,
    trunc(mod(sum(a.end_date - a.start_date) * 24 * 60,60)) minutes,
    round(mod(sum(a.end_date - a.start_date) * 24 * 60 * 60,60)) seconds,
    grouping_id(to_char(a.start_date, 'YYYY'), week_number, e.employee_id, e.first_name, e.last_name) the_grouping_id
from employees e
join emp_attendance a
    on a.employee_id = e.employee_id
group by grouping sets
(
    (to_char(a.start_date, 'YYYY'), week_number, e.employee_id, e.first_name, e.last_name),
    (to_char(a.start_date, 'YYYY'), week_number),
    (to_char(a.start_date, 'YYYY')),
    ()
)
order by week_number, employee_id;
```

```
THE_YEAR   WEEK_NUMBER   EMPLOYEE_ID   FIRST_NAME   LAST_NAME   HOURS   MINUTES   SECONDS   THE_GROUPING_ID
--------   -----------   -----------   ----------   ---------   -----   -------   -------   ---------------
    2021            30             1         Jane       Smith      11        45         8                 0
    2021            30             2         John         Doe       7         1        11                 0
    2021            30                                             18        46        19                 7
    2021            31             1         Jane       Smith      13        36         1                 0
    2021            31             2         John         Doe       3        27         0                 0
    2021            31                                             17         3         1                 7
    2021                                                           35        49        20                15
                                                                   35        49        20                31
```

Those results contain the numbers you want but are not in the exact format you want. I assume you will use a reporting tool for formatting, but if you want to do this purely in SQL you could use complicated `CASE(WHEN THE_GROUPING_ID = 'X' THEN ...` expressions to build the exact string you want.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you for your help and expertise

Comment: How difficult of a change would it be to your original solution if I wanted a grand total (all years). Below is an additional entry for the YYYY of 2022. Grand total = sum(2021)   + sum(2022). Thanks in advance for your expertise and patience. I'm a DBA and this is a bit out of my league.

INSERT INTO emp_attendance (employee_id, start_date, end_date,  week_number)VALUES (1, to_date('20220715 10:00:10','YYYYMMDD HH24:MI:SS'), to_date('20220715 12:10:11','YYYYMMDD HH24:MI:SS'),30);

Comment: @Beefstu Just add `()` as a grouping set to get a grand total.  You should upvote and accept this answer if answered your question.

Comment: Add a blank() like below or am I misunderstanding? I hope I correctly accepted the answer. There should be an accept button to make it obvious 
group by grouping sets
(
    (to_char(a.start_date, 'YYYY'), week_number, e.employee_id, e.first_name, e.last_name),
    (to_char(a.start_date, 'YYYY'), week_number),
    (to_char(a.start_date, 'YYYY'),())
)

Comment: @Beefstu See my updated answer with a grand total line.